# Where can I get mapped ground-truth of Pascal VOC2012 in COCO classes?

Tags: dataset

I'm trying to make use VOC2012/2007 dataset into COCO2014 training set ?
As far as I know that most of class (20) in VOC is also in COCO (80).

I think I can write code to map from VOC class to COCO class but I think I'm not the first one thinking like this, so anyone know where I can get such a thing please help to reduce time.

I tried to search but GG gave wrong results.

Comment: What do you mean by mapping classes from VOC into COCO? How would that code work?

Comment: VOC has many shared classes like: person, dog, cat, bird, planes ... Some might have different name but same concept like tv (coco) while tv-monitor (voc). I'm not just talking about xml and json. About classes correspondence.

Comment: I got it, thank you